# Android: externalize "@android:color/transparent" in the colors.xml resources file

Tags: android, colors

Hy,

I am using the next background colour @android:color/transparent for a ImageButton in the layout.xml. Could or should I externalize it in the colors.xml resources file?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by *externalize*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could but it depends on your needs. 
If you use that color in many different parts of your application it's best to place it in an external `xml` file. Sometimes you need to change the style of the whole application and it's easier to change the definition of that color instead of changing the color in many different places. If you're only using it in one single place then it is OK to leave it out of the external file.

EDIT:

```
<color name="my_background_color">@android:color/transparent</color>
```

Comment: Ok, so I would declare it as string or color in its specific resource fle?